# Solving a limit using probability theory.

Tags: probability, limits, central-limit-theorem

I’m stuck on the following probability question:
Calculate the limit

\begin{aligned}\cdot \\
\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum ^{n^{2}+3n}_{k=n^{2}+2n+1}e^{-n^{2}}\dfrac{n^{2k}}{k!}\end{aligned}

One direction I thought of was to use the binomial approximation \begin{aligned}\text{bin}(n,\lambda/n) \longrightarrow\:\text{Poisson}(\lambda) \quad\text{in distribution} \end{aligned}
and then use the CLT on the sum of the i.i.d. random variables that make up the binomial distribution. Problem is that this method just seems too complicated, and it seems like it’s the wrong way to go.

Comment: First, exercise your pattern-matching skills to write the individual term in the summation as the probability of something according to a well-known probability law.

Comment: Think about the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: Hint: This sum is just $ \mathbb P(n^2 + 2n + 1 \le X_n \le n^2 + 3n)$, where $X_n$ has Poisson distribution with parameter $n^2$. Hence, $\frac{X_n-n^2}{n}$ converges in distribution to standard gaussian.

Comment: Conceptually, you can look at Poisson($n^2$) as being approximately  Binomial($n^3,1/n$) for large $n$, and then apply CLT to that. Formalizing that approach is sort of messy if you don't have some kind of quantitative variation of CLT in the setting of the binomial distribution, but it will get you the answer anyway. Working formally, you are probably better off working with the Poisson distribution from scratch, e.g. by comparing characteristic functions.

Comment: Using the Stirling's asymptotics of Gamma-function
$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum ^{n^{2}+3n}_{k=n^{2}+2n+1}e^{-n^{2}}\dfrac{n^{2k}}{k!}=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_2^3e^{-\frac{t^2}2}dt=\frac12\left(\operatorname{erf}\big(\frac3{\sqrt2}\big)-\operatorname{erf}\big(\sqrt2\big)\right)=0.214002...$$